# Gradle task of project depend on task of other project

Tags: android, gradle

I have an android project with two different apps.

This is my current structure:

```
appA/
  buid.gradle
  ...
appB/
  buid.gradle
  ...
settings.gradle
gradlew
```

*settings.gradle* is the following:

```
include ':appA'
include ':appB'
```

To test *appA*, *appB* needs to be installed on the emulator.

Right now everything works if I first install both apps and then run *appA* tests

```
./gradlew installDebug              # install both apps apks
./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest   # runs tests on both apps (appB does not have any)
```

How can I explicitly say that *connecedInstrumentTest* of *appA* dependes on *installDebug* of *appB*?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the parent build.gradle file you can state:

> tasks.getByPath(':appA:connectedInstrumentTest').dependsOn(':appB:installDebug')

Or within appA's build.gradle you can add this line:

```
connectedInstrumentTest.dependsOn(':appB:installDebug')
```

Or an equivalent way to say the same thing in appA's build.gradle:

```
connectedInstrumentTest {
   dependsOn: ':appB:installDebug'
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. The parent build gradle just needs that line. Thanks

Comment: @Joao-trindade I've added information about adding the task dependency declaration in appA's build.gradle.  Having a parent build.gradle is a good thing but in case you don't want it, try one of the alternative methods I added to the answer.

Comment: I tried the later suggestion of adding it to appA's build.gradle, but I get an error message saying "Could not find property 'connectedInstrumentTest' on project '...'.

Comment: Resolved the issue myself, connectedInstrumentTest isn't an actual task, but connectedCheck is. So you should really reference as :appA:connectedCheck

Answer (score 2):

In module `:appA`'s `build.gradle` add this:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.getByName("connectedInstrumentTest") {
        dependsOn(":appB:installDebug")
    }
}
```